A Combinatoric Identity Involving Binomial Coefficients: $\sum^{n}_{r=1} {n \choose r} (-1)^r \frac{2^r-1}{2r}= \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r}$
Recently I came across this combinatoric identity:
$$
\begin{equation}
\sum^{n}_{r=1} {n \choose r} (-1)^r \frac{2^r-1}{2r}
\end{equation} = \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r}
$$
I have verified that this works numerically but am struggling to put together a general proof. It seems like there should be an easy way of looking at it due to the simplicity of the right hand side.

Engineer: If something works, don't touch it. In a similar way, if it works don't try to prove it.

@AnneBauval yes i did, thanks for the correction.

A simple proof of a general result using generating functions is in my answer.

$$\begin{align}\sum^n_{r=1}\binom nr(-1)^r\frac{2^r-1}r&=\sum^n_{r=1}\binom nr(-1)^r\int_1^2t^{r-1}dt\\
&=\int_1^2\frac1t\sum^n_{r=1}\binom nr(-t)^rdt\\
&=\int_1^2\frac{(1-t)^n-1}tdt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{(-s)^n-1}{1+s}ds\\
&=-\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-s)^kds\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n(-1)^r\int_0^1s^{r-1}ds\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-1)^r}r.
\end{align}$$

wow, would never have thought of that, thanks!

To see how this identity was designed, just take definite integral from $1$ to $t$ from the both sides of the following identity with respect to $a$, and then set $t=2$:
$$\sum^{n}_{r=1}\big((-1)(a-1)\big)^{r-1}=\frac{\big((-1)(a-1) \big)^{n}-1}{(-1)(a-1)-1}=\sum^{n}_{r=1} {n \choose r} (-a)^{r-1}. $$
You may complete it yourself.
Using this approach, you can generate other identities.

The identity mentioned is a particular case of a general identity
based on generating functions.
Given an infinite sequence  $\,(b_1,b_2,\dots),\,$ define its
exponential generating function (EGF) as
$$ g(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}. \tag1 $$
Multiply this by $\,e^{-x}\,$ to get another EGF
$$ f(x) := e^{-x}g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}. \tag2 $$
Using binomial convolution,
the new sequence  $\,(a_1,a_2,\dots)\,$ is also given by
$$ a_{n+1} := \sum_{r=0}^n {n \choose r}(-1)^r b_{n+1-r}. \tag3 $$
Similarly, since $\, g(x) = e^xf(x),\,$ the following is also true
$$ b_{n+1} = \sum_{r=0}^n {n \choose r} a_{n+1-r}. \tag4 $$
Reverse the summation index to get
$$ b_{n+1} = \sum_{r=1}^{n+1} {n \choose r-1} a_r =
a_{n+1} + \sum_{r=1}^n {n \choose r-1} a_r. \tag5 $$
Use the Pascal triangle recursion to get
$$ b_{n+1}=\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose r}a_r
     -\sum_{r=1}^n{n \choose r}a_r. \tag6 $$
Use this to get the telescoping sum result
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n b_r = \sum_{r=1}^n{n \choose r}a_r. \tag7 $$
Now specialize to $\,b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}n.\,$ Its EGF is
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}
 \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}. \tag8 $$
From equation $(2)$ the EGF of $\,a_n\,$ is
$$ f(x) = e^{-x} g(x) = \frac{e^{-2x} - e^{-x}}{x} = 
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(1-2^{n+1})}{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!}.
 \tag9 $$
This implies that
$$ a_n = (-1)^n\frac{2^n-1}n. \tag{10} $$
Use the special values of $\,a_n\,$ and $\,b_n\,$ in equation $(7)$
to get
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{(-1)^r}r =
  \sum_{r=1}^n{n \choose r}(-1)^r\frac{2^r-1}r. \tag{11} $$

We want to show that
$$\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} \frac{2^r-1}{r}
= \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-1)^r}{r}.$$
One approach is to show that both sides have the same generating function.
The left hand side yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} \frac{2^r-1}{r} z^n
&= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r (2^r-1)}{r} \sum_{n=r}^\infty \binom{n}{r} z^n \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r (2^r-1)}{r} \cdot \frac{z^r}{(1-z)^{r+1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r}\left(\left(\frac{-2z}{1-z}\right)^r - \left(\frac{-z}{1-z}\right)^r \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \left(-\log\left(1+\frac{2z}{1-z}\right)+\log\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z}\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \left(-\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)+\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{-\log(1+z)}{1-z}.
\end{align}
The right hand side yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-1)^r}{r} z^n
&= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r}{r} \sum_{n=r}^\infty z^n \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r}{r} \cdot \frac{z^r}{1-z} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-z)^r}{r} \\
&= \frac{-\log(1+z)}{1-z}.
\end{align}
